# PHP not displaying anything in MAMP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mamp

Im very new to PHP and was trying to get record information to display on a php page using the MAMP server environment.

The attributes are productID, productName, productDescription and productPrice.

I've been able to get really basic PHP to run fine but every time I open this php file, nothing displays, I was wandering if it might be to do with the location I placed the php file. It is currently in htdocs. would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
<?php
    //connection to db
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

    //choosing db
    mysql_select_db(primrose);

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM products";

    $records mysql_query(sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">  
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>

    <?php
    //loops over each record and for each a new record is set into the variable products
    while(products=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$products['productName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$products['productDescription']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    } //end while
    ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change php.ini and set display_errors to On and error_reporting to E_ALL. read the error.

Comment: `$records mysql_query(sql);` - basic PHP syntax errors, and you're probably running with all debug options turned off. That is **NOT** a good idea, especially when you're first starting out. Turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your php.ini, then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because (I think) this line is bad:

```
mysql_select_db(primrose);
```

Add quotes around the name of db:

```
mysql_select_db("primrose");
```

Also this line:

```
$records mysql_query(sql);
```

change to

```
$records = mysql_query($sql);
```

and this:

```
while(products=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
```

to

```
while($products=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
```

**NOTE 1:**

- Do not use `mysql` functions since, they are deprecatid. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

**NOTE 2:**

Let's turn on your error reporting with these two rows in the top of your PHP file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You have a lot of syntax errors. Let's use an IDE to identify them.

So your final code like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 //connection to db
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
//choosing db
mysql_select_db("primrose");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM products";
$records = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    //loops over each record and for each a new record is set into the variable products
    while($products=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$products['productName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$products['productDescription']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } //end while
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This helped more than I needed, thank you!
Will be sure to use error reporting from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to on just after to open'ed PHP.
If not, make sure that error reporting is turned on in your php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php